# FFmpeg Error: invalid data found when processing input

Tags: ffmpeg

I am having an issue with FFMPEG while trying to encode to flv

Here is my command

```
ffmpeg -i 182.1.mov -b 250k -deinterlace -vcodec flv1 -acodec mp3 182.1.flv
```

Yes FLV should be installed correctly, when I a run ffmpeg -codecs it does list flv1 as an option with the abilities `DEV.L.`

This is the error I recieve

```
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: Please provide the complete ffmpeg console output that shows up after you enter your command. Without it we can only make guesses as to what your issue actually is. Also, why `flv1`? Hardly anyone uses that anymore and it's a poor encoder compared to `libx264`.

Comment: Updated, I was going with flv1 because I assumed that was the codec for flv video, it needs to be flash as a fallback for my h264 and ogg and webm formats

Comment: Current versions of Flash can play H264 video in an MP4 container -- this has been the case for several years. You do not need FLV1 video. It looks awful anyway.

Comment: This is not the complete console output, unfortunately. There is additional information I'm looking for other than the actual error message. However, I do not see any reason to use flv1 when you are apparently already providing H.264 video. Same for "ogg": just about everything (I'm referring to browsers here) that supports the dated Theora in ogg supports VP8 in webm.

Comment: ok cool, I will use the h264 and see if I have any issues, for now I will use that

Comment: The complete output will still be useful, so I can provide an answer; specifically for those who may encounter this same issue and end up on this page.